# JQuery clicking an element after reloading the page

Tags: jquery

I have a small bit of code which basically when you click a button the page is reloaded and then once it reloaded it then click on a tab on that page.

This isn't working whats happening is when I click the button it starts reloading the page and the clicks the tab before finishing and then when it finishes reloading the page it redirects me back to the first tab

Here is the code:

```
$('.continue').click(function() {
    window.location.reload(true);
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + 'controller_integration' + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

I feel like I need some sort of delay when reloading the page before clicking the tab. Or a way to only click the tab once the page has fully reloaded.

Comment: You can't have JavaScript run *after* the page has changed. Why reload the page at all?

Comment: When you reload the page it is a whole new page, so what you have done before is all gone. You should probably pass something in the url or in cookies. E.g. http://url?tab=mytab then in your code you check for that and show the tab you want.

Comment: Surround the code that you want to executed after the page is loaded in $(document).ready(function () { //your code here });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a value in sessionStorage and check it on page load, to know that you should do an action.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('selectControllerIntegration')) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('selectControllerIntegration');
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + 'controller_integration' + '"]').tab('show');
  }

  $('.continue').click(function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectControllerIntegration', 'true');
    window.location.reload(true);
  });
});
```